# get size of file before download from amazon s3 in android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-progressbar

I have developed an app in which I have an ASyncTask that downloads a file from Amazon s3 server.
As the related files are quite large sized, I need to show a progress bar when the download happens and a spiral progress bar doesn't look good here when it keeps rotating and irritates the user.
I need to use a horizontal style progress bar for which I need to know the size of the file to be downloaded.
Does anybody know of any way to know the file size before downloading it from amazon s3.

This is the downloading code that I have used..

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        TransferManager manager = new TransferManager(access);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Downloads", downFile);
        fileDownloaded = "/Downloads/"+ downFile;
        file.setWritable(true);
        Download down = manager.download("files", fileToDown, file );
        try {
            down.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

'downFile' is the file location where I am saving it on external directory.
'fileToDown' is the file path on server that is to be downloaded.
'/Downloads/' is the new directory that I have created to store files on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you are using a code something like this,

```
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        // getting file length
        int lengthOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
```

the method `getContentLength()` will return to you the size of the file.

**UPDATE 1:**

I checked the java docs of Amazon about the TransferManager and Download class. There were method and listener that might be useful to display your progress and try using them.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#getProgress()

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferProgress.html

```
getProgress() //This will return TransferProgress object. See the links above
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#addProgressListener(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ProgressListener)

```
addProgressListener
```

This will able you I think to set up a progressListener.

**UPDATE 2:**

TransferProgress is an object which has bunch of informations about the progress of your download. It has bytes transferred, total bytes transferred and transfer percentage. Look at the methods detail.

[image]

Comment: i am downloading file from amazon s3 server and it does not require any URL, i have simply provided it with the access keys and the file path to be downloaded.

Comment: but do you use URLConnection class? It would be better to post your code.

Comment: i need to add a progress bar for which i need file size before download..
i used progress listener and it is not helpful in this case.

Comment: I think base on their library you don't need to get the actual size to establish progress you just need to get the progress and display it on an android view.

You said you have used the progress listener and getProgress what is the output then? If it crashed or you have blank output then you might doing it wrong.

Comment: The getProgress() returns the following: "com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.TransferProgressImpl@40d661b0"
I dont know how to use this to get progress.. it returns this string with the last number changed(not in serial order) at each progress.

Comment: Oh no, you have just printed the object `getProgress()` returns `TransferProgress object`. Then look at the documentation of the list of methods of TransferProgress you will see that it has getters [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferProgress.html). There are getters there for bytes and total bytes transfered as well as transferred in percentage.